# How can I make regex find a string a certain distance away?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For example, this is what I came up with so far

`lasts{0,1}.*?(\d).*?doggs`

The beginning part could be either `last` or `lasts` with an s.

Now, I want to look a maximum of 10 characters ahead of wherever it finds `lasts{0,1}` If it finds a digit within those 10 characters, look again to see if anywhere within a maxmimum of 10 characters is the string `doggs`

Is this even possible?

This is an example

> So I figure if I use them about 7-8 hours a day they should last about 5.8 doggs. That works out

I want to only get the 5

Comment: Could you provide some testcases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some more limiting quantifiers:

```
lasts?.{0,10}?(\d).{0,10}doggs
      ^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL7gP9/2)

Pattern explanation:

- `lasts?` - match either `last` or `lasts`
- `.{0,10}?` - match 0 to 10 characters **as few as possible** other than a newline (use DOTALL modifier to also match a newline)
- `\d` - a digit
- `.{0,10}` - see above
- `doggs` - match a literal character sequence `doggs`.

Comment: I updated the OP with an example, yours works fine except it only get the 8

Comment: But there is no `doggs`. What is the requirement?

Comment: See the updated answer and [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL7gP9/2). The main point is to use a lazy limiting quantifier (`{n,m}?`).

Answer (score 0):

```
`lasts{0,1}.{0,10}\d.{0,10}doggs`
```

The `lasts{0,1}` can be replaced by `lasts?`.

Comment: But what if sometimes it's last and something it's lasts?

Comment: The `?` only applies to the immediate-previous character, i.e. `s`.

Comment: `(lasts)?` would mean "nothing or `lasts`".

Comment: So i got `lasts?.{0,10}(\d).{0,10}doggs` The only issue with this, is that if there is a decimal, it only gets the second digit

Comment: Change the first `.` to `\D` so that it will not match digits.